# Is there any Opensource Python video event Detection code available on Internet?

Tags: python, image-processing

Is there any real time video event detection projects available online?I have googled and i got projects in c++ but i couldn't find any project in python.If anybody got any idea or github link,it would be a great help?

Comment: Python is great, but I doubt it's a language of choice for real-time video analysis

Comment: @agg3l most of the things that would do video/cv are written in C/C++ and python could easily bind to those. The loss in speed is marginal.

Comment: @RafaelBarros sure, but I doubt that's a solution questioner looking for. Yet may be you right about it

Comment: Try [opencv](http://opencv.org/)

Answer (score 2):

I can't post a comment because I haven't got 50 reputation yet, but does https://github.com/arturaugusto/display_ocr look like something you're looking for? If not, try googling OCR for more about image recognition.